# Symfony : loss of an URL parameter between executeNew / executeCreate

Tags: php, forms, inheritance, parameters, symfony1

I'm implementing concrete inheritance in my model. So I'm trying to do (i'm taking example upon jobeet) :

When a user try to post his CV, he'll be redirected on a page on which he will be choosing his main skill (Developper / Network). Both of dev/network inherits from future_employees, cause it has common informations in it.

If he he chooses developper, [the form displayed contained additionnal information](http://pastie.org/private/giykemr6ptxi8pak3pzbg) + common information thanks to the concrete inheritance => **it works great**

But [as soon as the create action is called](http://pastie.org/private/voy4ljhjv7gdoko8qk5jpa), it looses the parameter 'category' and redirects me to a `futureEmployeeForm` form full of error (missing required parameters), which is logic, because i did not fill a `futureEmployeeForm` but a `developperForm`

What's going on ? How to preserve the parameter so that error can be fixed ? Or maybe i'm not using a good method to resolve this inheritance case ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What does the form look like? I.e., how is the category parameter being passed to the create action? My guess is that it's not in `$request->getParameter('category')` but rather in `$request->getPostParameter('developperForm[category]')`.